# use of conditional for recount of habits

Tags: tense, past-tense, american-english, conditional-constructions

If I start using the conditional to talk about repeated actions or habits, do I have to maintain it during the whole recount or can I switch to simple past in the next sentences?

> He would turn up at the gallery, saying he had just been in the
>   neighborhood, and she would pretend to believe him and invite him for
>   coffee or lunch. If she happened to be busy, Michael **would
>   occupy/occupied** himself by admiring the paintings. Or he **would
>   take/took** one of the books from the shelf...

Comment: I think you want *account*, not *recount*: *recount* is used as a noun only as a derivative of the sense "count again", not of the sense "narrate".

Comment: The dictionaries have both meanings. (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recount) But maybe one is more idiomatic than the other. Thanks!

Comment: Check again: the *verb* has both meanings, the noun only one.

Comment: Note, by the way, that the *would*s in this passage are not 'conditional' but 'habitual'.

Comment: Only this dictionary disagrees. But I believe you. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recount

Comment: Personally, I think it depends on the tone you want to create. Simple past sounds more matter-of-fact and "would" sounds a little bit more mysterious and romantic (the style, not the emotion).

Comment: In the meantime, grammatically, yes, I think you could use either construction for both of those sentences.

Comment: The only option I wouldn't choose is "would occupy + took." As a reader, I feel like the switch between tenses would be a little jarring.

Answer (score 2):

You are not required to employ the same construction in both consequence clauses, but it's a good idea to do so. Shifting the construction confuses your reader and sets her to wondering what nuance of meaning the shift implies.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with StoneyB on this one.  You're describing a collection of events all prefaced by "if".  It is split into several sentences, but all of it is based on the conditional.

Had "when" been used instead of "if", it's usage with a past tense description of the condition ("when she happened to be busy"), would make it a narrative about past events.  Sometimes she was busy and sometimes she wasn't.  On those past occasions when she was, this is what happened.

"If" describes a rule to apply to future events.  Combining that with a past tense description of the condition changes the perspective of the narration. It describes events as if they haven't happened yet; taking the reader back in time to before the event and explaining from that vantage point what would happen in case the "if" condition is true.  You can't use past tense for any of what is based on the "if" since you're describing things that haven't happened yet (in the timeframe of the story).

So it should be "would occupy" and "would take".